# Combine multiple arrays with identica keys and different values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this two arrays that are generated in two foreach loops and I want to set the first array as keys and the second one as values.

after I use this code

```
foreach ($difference AS $j) {
   $fv = $cate->getFilterValueByFeatureID($j);
        foreach ($fv AS $z) {
             $array = array(
                  $j => $z
                 );
              var_dump($array);
          }
 }
```

this is what I get

```
array(1) {
  [6]=>
  int(15)
}

array(1) {
   [6]=>
   int(20)
 }

array(1) {
    [8]=>
  int(26)
}

array(1) {
  [8]=>
  int(27)
    }

array(1) {
    [8]=>
    int(33)
}
```

and I want this result

```
array(1){
[6] => array(
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 20
)
array(1){
[8] => array(
        [0] => 26
        [1] => 27
        [2] => 33
)
```

Comment: Just need to change to $array[$j][] = $z; (saying $j is the key, and that key is pointing to an array were you want to add a new array element which is $z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this (untested)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($difference AS $j) {
  $fv = $cate->getFilterValueByFeatureID($j);
    foreach ($fv AS $z) {
         if(!isset($result[$j])) $result[$j] = [];

         $result[$j][] = $z;
      }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: You can remove this line `if(!isset($result[$j])) $result[$j] = [];`. If `$j` not set, PHP will create empty array automatically

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks it worked but i didnt get all the vlaues but after i did what dWinder sayed it worked perfectly